# How to make a new account without GameCenter and no backup

Tags: clash-of-clans

How would I go about making a new account without using GameCenter or a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Clear data of your clash of clans game in setting - - > Apps ( if you already have CoC installed  )  And then open your game.  Just go through the tutorial and then when it ask you to sign in, just ignore.
And yeah, you now successfully created your game without having any backup account.

But be careful you will lose your game if you change settings.